# why does the output of this readline() changes with print(line) function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code to read a textfile.

```
fin= open('C:\\words.txt')
line=fin.readlines()
print(line)
```

It produces the following output:-

```
['aa\n', 'aah\n', 'aahed\n', 'aahing\n', 'aahs\n', 'aal\n', 'aalii\n', 'aaliis\n', 'aals\n', 'aardvark\n', 'aardvarks\n', 'aardwolf\n', 'aardwolves\n', 'aas\n', 'aasvogel\n', 'aasvogels\n', 'aba\n', 'abaca\n', 'abacas\n', 'abaci\n', 'aback\n', 'abacus\n', 'abacuses\n', 'abaft\n', 'abaka\n', 'abakas\n', 'abalone\n', 'abalones\n']
```

However, when I omit `print(line)` i.e.

```
fin= open('C:\\words.txt')
fin.readlines()
```

Then output becomes:-

```
['aa\n',    
'aah\n', 
'aahed\n',    
'aahing\n',     
'aahs\n',     
'aal\n', 
'aalii\n',
'aaliis\n',
'aals\n',
'aardvark\n',
'aardvarks\n',
'aardwolf\n',
'aardwolves\n',
'aas\n',
'aasvogel\n',
'aasvogels\n',
'aba\n',
'abaca\n',
'abacas\n',
'abaci\n',
'aback\n',
'abacus\n',
'abacuses\n',
'abaft\n',
'abaka\n',
'abakas\n',
'abalone\n',
'abalones\n']
```

Why is such behaviour when `print()` function is introduced??

Comment: No repro. If I omit the `print`, then there's (obviously) no output.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess that you are using a Jupyter notebook.  `print` writes its output as characters directly, and doesn't understand how things should be formatted, so it's all run together.  Without `print`, the notebook can see that the value is a list, and can format it nicely for you:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I am using Jupyter notebook..or plz guide me which IDE is better, if not Jupyter notebook, where there will be a unique output for both cases??

Comment: I am getting the following output: 
d=list(range(1,10))
print(d)
output is:-  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

                                                                                                                              
But if I simply write d, then output becomes same as before:-                               
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
​No Diffference as  such?????

Comment: Jupyter notebook is great, there's no reason to switch.  `x` and `print(x)` will often produce different output, in any environment.  I used bigger numbers because Jupyter puts the whole list on one line if it fits.

Comment: Yes, you r right when i use biggger numbers, it behaves in the same way as you've shown earlier..thanks a lot

Comment: So, Mr. Ned, while writing a code, what do u suggest?? Should one always write print() or smthing else??any advice??

Comment: My advice is learn what the tools do, decide what result you want, then use the appropriate tool.